# Derivative result is $0 \over 0$. Does it imply the point isn't differentiable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

$$f'(x) = {2x \over {4(x^2)^{3 \over 4}}}$$

for $x_0$ the derivative is $0 \over 0$, Which is defined as infinity as much as I know.
Is it sufficient to say the above in order to prove $x_0=0$ isn't differentiable, or should I explain it in another way?

Thanks

Comment: What is your starting function? Is it $x\mapsto \sqrt x$? Defined where? At $x=0$ you need to use the definitionto try to see if it is differentiable there.

Comment: $\frac00$ is indeterminate, not defined as infinity. If you start from $f(x) = (x^2)^{1/4}$, the graph has a cusp with vertical tangent at $0$, $f$ is not differentiable in $0$.

Comment: $\displaystyle f'(x) = \frac{2x}{4(x^2)^{\frac{3}{4}}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. My guess is that the original function was $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, and that you're trying to prove that $f$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$. Like @GitGud said, you should use the definition of differentiable to prove it.

Comment: *Any* derivative whatsoever that you compute starting with a continuous $f$ is going to give you an expression of the form $0/0$. You cannot conclude anything from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

(1) Canonically, $\frac00$ has *no* definition — which is different from being defined as infinity.  In fact, the classic definition of a derivative involves the limit of two things which go to $0$: just think of, for instance, taking the derivative of $f(t)=t^2$, where the result is $f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{2xh+h^2}{h}$.  Clearly this is a $\frac00$ limit, but that doesn't mean that the derivative is necessarily infinite.

(2) You can simplify your expression substantially: rewrite the denominator as a direct power of $x$ using the rule $\left(a^b\right)^c=a^{bc}$, then rewrite the entire fraction as a single term in $x$ using the rule $\frac{a^b}{a^c}=a^{b-c}$.  You should be able to clean up the constant terms in the process.  Once you do this, you'll find that you no longer have a $\frac00$ limit and can evaluate it more directly.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "$\frac{0}{0}$" is **not** infinity, but rather it is undefined. When you get something like that, you should check using limits what happens. You have to compute both
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)$$
$$\lim_{x\to0^-}f'(x)$$
If they disagree, or are infinite, then $f'$ is not continuous at $0$, if they agree to some finite value, then that value is $f'(0)$.

Comment: Consider the function $f(x) = 1$ if $x \ne 0$, and $f(0) = 0$. Then $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^-} f'(x) = 0$, but $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: @T.Bongers Yes, I worked in the assumption that the function is continuous and differentiable almost everywhere.